# How do I get a DataGridView bound to an existing DataTable to display a DropDownList column?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcombobox

I'm trying to create a DataGridView with the following characteristics:
- Its DataSource is a DataTable I created with several columns in it. 
- One of the columns in the DataGridView displays a DropDownList that I populate (which corresponds to a column already in my DataTable).
- The value selected in the DropDownList populates the underlying column in the DataTable.

So far I was able to do this by setting the DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns property to false, then manually creating the columns by looping through the columns in the DataTable for all the non-DropDownList columns, and using a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn (setting that column's DataSource Property to a list I created) for the column I wanted to have as a DropDownList.

However, this seems both messy and lengthy (and near impossible to generalize). Is there a better way to achieve this same result?